# What is the busiest route of Turkish Airlines in 2017?

Tags: passenger, airlines, flight-path

What is the busiest non-domestic route of Turkish Airlines:

1. in terms of passenger number,
2. in terms of number of flights performed per year?

Is there a database that I can look for such kind of statistics for all other European airlines?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited for travel.SE

Comment: @Pondlife As a regular user of travel.SE, I'm not at all convinced that this question is on-topic there. They'd likely bounce it straight back here saying that it's a question about the airline industry, not about travelling. (As a general rule of thumb, ask yourself, "Would any traveller need to know this to make their trip?" I think the answer is clearly not. A traveller might need to know how busy a particular route was, to know how far in advance they should buy a ticket. But it would never be useful to know an airline's busiest route.)

Comment: @Pondlife further to what David said, the fact that it's potentially on topic elsewhere isn't a good reason to say it's off topic here. This is very much about aviation in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's fair enough, I'm not very familiar with travel.SE's scope. This just doesn't feel much like aviation to me, but that's OK, that's just my opinion :-)

Comment: @Notts90 I disagree, but that's why SE has votes :-) If most people feel it's on topic that's fine.

Comment: @Pondlife I think the question fits to aviation title quite well. What is "aviation" then? We should not narrow-down our minds. I am sorry that the question was shot-down by 5 members. Is that possible to make a voting whether the question on-topic?

Comment: You can check the help center for [what's on topic here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but like all SE sites there are always grey areas, and ultimately we consider each question individually. Right now, people have already voted that it's off-topic but you can always edit the question to make it more relevant, or you can ask in [chat] for people to reconsider and vote to re-open. For me, the question has very little to do with operating aircraft and that's why I voted to close. Others may feel - and vote - differently, and that's completely OK.

Comment: @Pondlife Pardon me! Thanks for the detailed answer. Of course, everyone can have different opinions. However, does aviation mean only operating an aircraft? Why should not it include operating an aircraft (related) business?

Answer (score 3):

[According](http://www.globes.co.il/en/article-turkish-airlines-vp-israel-is-our-busiest-route-1001003747) to Turkish Airlines VP Ziya Taskent, they are adding a ninth weekly flight between Tel Aviv and Istanbul. He mentioned that:

> 695,000 [passengers] flew roundtrip with the airline in 2014 [between
>   Tel Aviv and Istanbul], 4.86% more than in 2013, making it the leading
>   foreign airline in Israel

The largest number of airports [served by the carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Airlines_destinations) is Germany with 14 destinations.

For other European carriers as requested, the Wikipedia article '[List of busiest passenger air routes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_passenger_air_routes)' is a good starting point.

Comment: This is extremely interesting to me. Last week, I randomly came across a flight path (Turkish Airlines) between Istanbul and Amman (Jordan). I noticed that they clearly explicitly fly around Israel to avoid it. I thought that the airline may have had diplomatic issues with Israel but I guess not. Any guesses why they do that? Here: https://flightaware.com/live/flight/THY812/history/20180125/1835Z/LTBA/OJAI

Comment: @SamCreamer:  I'd encourage you to ask that as a new question.  Interestingly, the return flight flies directly over Israel:  https://flightaware.com/live/flight/THY813/history/20180126/0355Z/OJAI/LTBA

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That is very interesting... That leads me to believe that there are some restrictions on Jordan's end. I will ask this as a new question so that others can have more visibility in case they are curious.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have asked a new question here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48003/thy812-explicitly-flies-around-israel-but-return-flight-thy813-flies-right-ov